# How to post array parameters with HttpComponents

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I want to perform this command with Apache http-components (4.1.2)

```
 curl  --data "strings[]=testOne&string-keys[]=test.one&strings[]=testTwo&string-keys[]=test.two&project=Test" https://api.foo.com/1/string/input-bulk
```

The target api need **strings** and **string-keys** parameters as *array*, which mean repeating **strings[]** and **string-keys[]** for each parameter.

This curl command works fine but with Http-component, while I got exactly the same parameters.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

```
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "project", PROJECT_NAME ) );

    for ( Entry entry : newEntries )
    {
        params.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "string-keys[]", entry.getKey() ) );
        params.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "strings[]", entry.getValue() ) );
        params.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "context[]", "" ) );
    }

    URI uri = URIUtils.createURI( "https", "api.foo.com", -1, "/1/string/input-bulk", null, null );

    UrlEncodedFormEntity paramEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity( params );
    logger.info( "POST params : {}", EntityUtils.toString( paramEntity ) );
    HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost( uri );
    httpRequest.setEntity( paramEntity );

    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute( httpRequest );
```

The POST params looks like :

```
POST params : project=Test&string-keys%5B%5D=test.one&strings%5B%5D=TestOne&string-keys%5B%5D=test.two&strings%5B%5D=TestTwo
```

If I put them behind --data in curl, it works, but not with HttpCoponents.
Can someone explain me why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the header "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in your httpRequest

```
    httpRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute( httpRequest );
```

Hopefully that will work

Comment: Have you tried using StringEntity instead of UrlEncodedFormEntity?

Comment: Ok so using StringEntity doesn't change anything, it seems my problem has nothing to do with encoding. I update my question.

Comment: Let's try one more thing. I read in several places that input form with same name should be group together and separated by comma. Maybe curl does the grouping for you and Android doesn't. So for strings[] with value1 and value2, you should have strings[]=value1,value2 in the key value pair.

Comment: thanks but I decided to switch to httpclient 3.x, and all work like a charm (+1 for your help ;))

Comment: @tbruyelle What worked ? You are using String Entity ? I have similar issue...I want to send List<Long> ...not sure how to do that. I am making webservice call. There is WebClient in cxf which directly takes list but i am stuck with httpclient 4.x

Comment: @tbruyelle  How did it work? Do you have working sample to share?