# How to POST a collection using Apache HTTP components

Tags: java, http, apache-httpcomponents

Is it possible to POST a request using Apache HTTP-components with a parameter that is mapped to a collection?

This question was previously asked (here: [How to post array parameters with HttpComponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309237/how-to-post-array-parameters-with-httpcomponents)). No answer was provided as the user supposedly "switch[ed] to httpclient 3.x, and all work[ed] like a charm".

I do not want to do this as httpclient has been end-of-life'd, and succeeded by HttpComponents.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think still there is an answer. AFAIK it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get it from your collection into the parameter list yourself, I don't know the HttpComponents stuff, but I'm guessing they have no standard way to do that. But looking at the code that you refer to in your question, it's similar to what they are doing.

Also, you have to consider what is receiving the POST and what they expect the collection to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using list:

```
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IDToken1", "username"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IDToken2", "password"));

httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
```

From:
ClientFormLogin.java of

httpcomponents-client-4.1.3\examples\org\apache\http\examples\client